# take user input from console in nodejs iteratively?

Tags: javascript, node.js

How to take input from console in a loop ?

Let us suppose node promt asks how many students are in a class?
after this user enter 5, then there should be a promt asking 5 times "enter their name one by one",
and all name has to be stored in an array

Comment: Something like [`prompt`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prompt) would work for this.. (has more than double the amount of weekly downloads on NPM versus `readline-sync`)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
const readline = require('readline');
const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
});

let n;
let array = []

function mainfunction() {
    if( n == array.length){
        console.log("your output: ",  array)
        rl.close()
    }
    else{
        rl.question('enter student name one by one \n', (name) => {
            array.push(name)
            mainfunction()
        })
    }
 }

rl.question('enter the number of students ', (answer) => {
    n = answer
    mainfunction()
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this with the [readline-sync](https://www.npmjs.com/package/readline-sync) package

```
 var readline = require('readline-sync');

    let num = readline.question("how many students are in a class ?");
    let names=[];
    for(let i=0;i<=num;i++)
    {
      let name = readline.question("Enter Name?");
      names.push(name);
    }
    console.log(names);
```

Working repl-https://repl.it/repls/LightyellowEvenBusinesses

Comment: can it work in online challenges problem, like hackers earth etc etc

Comment: It should ,I guess try it :)